# Is ReliableSqlConnection Deprecated

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

The Microsoft documentation for ReliableSqlConnection reports that "This content and the technology described is outdated and is no longer being maintained".

Is the ReliableSqlConnection deprecated?

**Background on why I'm asking this question**

We recently migrated our website to the cloud as an Azure App Service and have a SQL Azure instance.

I'm in the process of making updates to handle transient errors for the Entity Framework queries and am now focusing on ADO.NET.

We use a ReliableSqlConnection throughout our application via a helper class that creates the new connection which includes retry logic.  This has been in place for several years.

Since SQL Azure has been around for many years, I'm finding many posts about best strategies.  Many reference using SqlConnection and others reference ReliableSqlConnection.

Is there a preferred connection for Azure SQL connections today?

Comment: This is baked into SqlConnection now.

Answer (score 2):

This is [baked into SqlClient itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/configurable-retry-logic?view=sql-server-ver16) now. The [Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/configurable-retry-logic-sqlclient-introduction?view=sql-server-ver16) in the docs explain how to open a connection with configurable retry options :

```
// Define the retry logic parameters
var options = new SqlRetryLogicOption()
{
    // Tries 5 times before throwing an exception
    NumberOfTries = 5,
    // Preferred gap time to delay before retry
    DeltaTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    // Maximum gap time for each delay time before retry
    MaxTimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
};

// Create a retry logic provider
SqlRetryLogicBaseProvider provider = SqlConfigurableRetryFactory.CreateExponentialRetryProvider(options);

// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object 
// Set the retry logic provider on the connection instance
connection.RetryLogicProvider = provider;
// Establishing the connection will retry if a transient failure occurs.
connection.Open();
```

Comment: I appreciate your responses.  We currently implement retry and timespan logic using a ReliableSqlConnection.  Do you know if it may be beneficial to switch ReliableSqlConnection out with SqlConnection?

Comment: The article you linked to is 8 years old. That alone is reason enough to switch. Any problems found with the retry logic are fixed in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but not the old P&P libraries